# Pass variable from controller to view and use the variable to display the data

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined variable: blog_data

Filename: views/savedata.php

Line Number: 4

Backtrace:

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/success_story_ci/application/views/savedata.php
Line: 4
Function: _error_handler

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/success_story_ci/application/controllers/Story.php
Line: 31
Function: view

File: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/success_story_ci/index.php
Line: 315
Function: require_once
```

```
    public function savedata(){

        if(!empty($this->input->post())){

            $data = array(
                          'cluster_det' => $this->input->post('Clust_det'),
                          'need_of_activity' => $this->input->post('need_of_the_activity'),
                          'intervention' => $this->input->post('intervention'),
                          'impact' => $this->input->post('impact'),
                          'key_stakeholders' => $this->input->post('Key_stakeholders'),
                          'beneficiaries' => $this->input->post('beneficiaries'),
                          'activity_det' => $this->input->post('activity_det'),
                          'reference_contact' => $this->input->post('reference_contact'),
                          'image' => 'imageaddress',//$this->input->post('image')
                          'title' => $this->input->post('title')
                          );

            $res = $this->db->insert('blog', $data);
            $id = $this->db->insert_id();
            $this->db->select('*');
            $this->db->from('blog');
            $this->db->where('id', $id);
            $blog_data = $this->db->get();

            $this->load->view('savedata', $blog_data);

            echo 'data saved';
            return true;
        }

    }

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('savedata');
    }
```

the above code is to pass a variable to the view ie the data insert command and the id from the last record so the last record is passed as variable `$blog_data` to view. 
Also required to send the variable at the view with codeigniter to display the blog entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$blog_data = $this->db->get();
```

to

```
$blog_data['blog_data'] = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

or

```
$blog_data['blog_data'] = $this->db->get()->row_array();
```

to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, To pass variable to `view`
Controller:

```
$data = array();
$data['blog_data'] = $blog_data;//from your model or db source
$this->load->view('savedata', $blog_data);
```

View

```
<?php echo'<pre>';print_r($blog_data);die; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this

```
$blog_data = $this->db->get()
```

and place this code

```
$blog_data['blog_data'] = $this->db->get()->row_array();
```

Comment: this is to get data from db but i wanna send data from controller to view, read question properly.

Answer (score 0):

when you are in your modal in the end you need your data in array format so we use

```
In modal:-
$query = $this->db->get('table_name');
    $result_var = $query->result_array();
    return $result_var;
In Controller :-
$this->modal->('modal_name');
$variable_name['For_view_pass_variable_name'] = $this->modal_name->modal_function_name;

try to use MVC pattren it will be helpful for you.
```

Comment: i require to use only controller to send data from controller to view. but thanks.